# Is there an english proverb/idiom/phrase for this translation?

Tags: phrases, idioms, proverbs

English is my second language and I was wondering if there is a proverb/idiom/phrase for this proverb/idiom in my language which directly translates to:

"Only who suffers can understand that suffering"

Comment: It's close, but no cigar: *when you laugh, the world laughs with you, when you cry, you cry alone*.

Comment: There is an idiomatic expression using blues music.  I cannot recall the exact phrasing, but it is something like "you can't play the blues if you haven't had the blues".

Comment: @UserEpsilon: That is an on-point suggestion. The man most frequently credited with the observation is Huddie Ledbetter (aka Lead Belly), back in the 1930s or 1940s. [One publication](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zf8IAQAAMAAJ&q=%22to+sing+the+blues%22+%22have+the+blues%22&dq=%22to+sing+the+blues%22+%22have+the+blues%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo0KOoiNXbAhXiHTQIHbv6CwAQ6AEIVDAI) that cites him uses this wording: "It takes a man that have the blues to sing the blues."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think either of these fit the description either.

**I complained my shoes were too tight, until I met a man with no feet**

and

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/walk+a+mile+in+our+shoes)
**walk a mile in (someone's) shoes**
"To spend time trying to consider or understand another person's perspectives, experiences, or motivations before making a judgment about them. I know that certain people can come across as selfish or mean-spirited, but you should try walking a mile in their shoes before you dismiss them too quickly."

Answer (score 1):

**learn (something) the hard way**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/learn+the+hard+way)

> To learn or discover something through personal experience, especially
>   that which is difficult, painful, or unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

A *general* saying is [you had to be there](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/you%20had%20to%20be%20there):

> used to say that people cannot understand something because they did not experience it or see it themselves · I know it sounds weird, but it was so funny. I guess you had to be there.

I can't think of an idiom that expresses the same thing but is *specific* to suffering.